# Catch errors in promise resolved with stream concatenation in node js

Tags: node.js, error-handling, stream, throw, through2

I need to catch errors thrown inside a stream event in promise resolution. Something like

```
function foo(){
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  resolve(res.pipe(transfomrStream).pipe(through2.obj(function(obj, enc, callback) {
    on('end', ()=>{ 
        await httpReq(...)
          .then((crudRes) => assert.strictEqual(somerthing))
      })
     )
   })
 })
}
```

how could i catch assert failure? I've tried to return error inside the last *pipe()* or in function calling but i only get *unhandled promise rejection*

Answer (score 0):

If you surround your code with a try catch you can at least see what your error is:

```
function foo(){
try{
 return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  resolve(res.pipe(transfomrStream).pipe(through2.obj(function(obj, enc, callback) {
    on('end', ()=>{ 
        await httpReq(...)
          .then((crudRes) => assert.strictEqual(somerthing))
      })
     )
   })
 })
 }
 catch(e) {
  console.log(e)
  reject()
}
}
```

Also, if you have an `await` you cannot use `.then()`. And you will have to make your function `async` if you're doing await.